# Mass email messages with personalised recommendations. No JS

Tags: html, css

I have created a recommendation service for users, and now want to send them personalised email. The service provides a RESTful API, eg:

`GET http://recser.net/recommend/user/john/first_item` returns

`{item: 2, link: "http://...link.html", image: "http://...image"}`.

I want John to receive an email message which in plain HTML would look like the one below:

`<html>
Dear John, have a look at this: <a href="http://...link.html"> <img src="http://...image"> </a>
<html>`

Unfortunately, I cannot write my own script to produce the message body and send the messages –that would be easy.
I cannot use JavaScript (it's a mail), which makes me think I am left with CSS –maybe creating a div class with href in it? I don't know much about CSS, and could not find anything.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your question here? How to generate the HTML customised to the user and then send the message? This would normally be done using server side using a language like C#, PHP or Ruby on Rails - you probably wouldn't be able to send the message in just JavaScript anyway (unless you were calling an external API to do the actual sending). Can you give more details of your environment? I'm not sure I understand the point about CSS, are you asking if it's possible to create a link solely in CSS (it's not).

Comment: Hi! My question is how to have a dynamic html which generates and inserts the right image and click. As said, it would be easy to write a script to generate the static HTML, or directly insert JS. But I cannot. If it is not possible with CSS (thanks for the info), then I have no idea how to do it... Cheers

Comment: Why can you not alter the HTML content or behaviour using server side logic/technologies? To change content using CSS would itself requiring changing the DOM by adding or removing styles, IDs or class names. CSS  is not scripted and therefore cannot run conditional content changes, beyond those by changing the selectors that exist in the document, or through media queries. Whatever generates the e-mail should be customising it, not relying on the client side to change it given the limitations you have already described. There is no "if clientName === 'john'" logic in CSS by design.

Comment: Additionally, only psuedo elements (before and after) can have their content changed in CSS, and this would be static content within the CSS file (although the file itself could be dynamically generated on the server). Background images can clearly have their paths changed, but this is again subject to a static URL for a given selector within the file. Dynamic CSS would have to be dynamically generated on the server.

Comment: I see... thanks. I think I'm following your advice and going to use server side services.